sympy integration with cosine function under a square root
I am trying to solve the integration
integrate( sqrt(1 + cos(2 * x)), (x, 0, pi) )

Clearly, through pen and paper this is not hard, and the result is:

But when doing this through Sympy, something does not seem correct.
I tried the sympy codes as below.
from sympy import *

x = symbols("x", real=True)
integrate(sqrt(1 + cos(2 * x)), (x, 0, pi)).doit()

It then gives me a ValueError saying something in the complex domain not defined. But I've already defined the symbol x as a variable in the real domain.
Here is the full error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 4
      1 from sympy import *
      3 x = symbols("x", real=True)
----> 4 integrate(sqrt(1 + cos(2 * x)), (x, 0, pi)).doit()

File C:\Dev_Tools\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sympy\integrals\integrals.py:1567, in integrate(meijerg, conds, risch, heurisch, manual, *args, **kwargs)
   1564 integral = Integral(*args, **kwargs)
   1566 if isinstance(integral, Integral):
-> 1567     return integral.doit(**doit_flags)
   1568 else:
   1569     new_args = [a.doit(**doit_flags) if isinstance(a, Integral) else a
   1570         for a in integral.args]

File C:\Dev_Tools\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sympy\integrals\integrals.py:499, in Integral.doit(self, **hints)
    497 if reps:
    498     undo = {v: k for k, v in reps.items()}
--> 499     did = self.xreplace(reps).doit(**hints)
    500     if isinstance(did, tuple):  # when separate=True
    501         did = tuple([i.xreplace(undo) for i in did])

File C:\Dev_Tools\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sympy\integrals\integrals.py:710, in Integral.doit(self, **hints)
    707 uneval = Add(*[eval_factored(f, x, a, b)
    708                for f in integrals])
    709 try:
--> 710     evalued = Add(*others)._eval_interval(x, a, b)
    711     evalued_pw = piecewise_fold(Add(*piecewises))._eval_interval(x, a, b)
    712     function = uneval + evalued + evalued_pw

File C:\Dev_Tools\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sympy\core\expr.py:956, in Expr._eval_interval(self, x, a, b)
    953     domain = Interval(b, a)
    954 # check the singularities of self within the interval
    955 # if singularities is a ConditionSet (not iterable), catch the exception and pass
--> 956 singularities = solveset(self.cancel().as_numer_denom()[1], x,
    957     domain=domain)
    958 for logterm in self.atoms(log):
    959     singularities = singularities | solveset(logterm.args[0], x,
    960         domain=domain)

File C:\Dev_Tools\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\solveset.py:2252, in solveset(f, symbol, domain)
   2250 if symbol not in _rc:
   2251     x = _rc[0] if domain.is_subset(S.Reals) else _rc[1]
-> 2252     rv = solveset(f.xreplace({symbol: x}), x, domain)
   2253     # try to use the original symbol if possible
   2254     try:

File C:\Dev_Tools\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\solveset.py:2276, in solveset(f, symbol, domain)
   2273     f = f.xreplace({d: e})
   2274 f = piecewise_fold(f)
-> 2276 return _solveset(f, symbol, domain, _check=True)

File C:\Dev_Tools\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\solveset.py:1060, in _solveset(f, symbol, domain, _check)
   1057     result = Union(*[solver(m, symbol) for m in f.args])
   1058 elif _is_function_class_equation(TrigonometricFunction, f, symbol) or \
   1059         _is_function_class_equation(HyperbolicFunction, f, symbol):
-> 1060     result = _solve_trig(f, symbol, domain)
   1061 elif isinstance(f, arg):
   1062     a = f.args[0]

File C:\Dev_Tools\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\solveset.py:612, in _solve_trig(f, symbol, domain)
    610 sol = None
    611 try:
--> 612     sol = _solve_trig1(f, symbol, domain)
    613 except _SolveTrig1Error:
    614     try:

File C:\Dev_Tools\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\solveset.py:688, in _solve_trig1(f, symbol, domain)
    685 if g.has(x) or h.has(x):
    686     raise _SolveTrig1Error("change of variable not possible")
--> 688 solns = solveset_complex(g, y) - solveset_complex(h, y)
    689 if isinstance(solns, ConditionSet):
    690     raise _SolveTrig1Error("polynomial has ConditionSet solution")

File C:\Dev_Tools\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\solveset.py:2284, in solveset_complex(f, symbol)
   2283 def solveset_complex(f, symbol):
-> 2284     return solveset(f, symbol, S.Complexes)

File C:\Dev_Tools\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\solveset.py:2252, in solveset(f, symbol, domain)
   2250 if symbol not in _rc:
   2251     x = _rc[0] if domain.is_subset(S.Reals) else _rc[1]
-> 2252     rv = solveset(f.xreplace({symbol: x}), x, domain)
   2253     # try to use the original symbol if possible
   2254     try:

File C:\Dev_Tools\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\solveset.py:2276, in solveset(f, symbol, domain)
   2273     f = f.xreplace({d: e})
   2274 f = piecewise_fold(f)
-> 2276 return _solveset(f, symbol, domain, _check=True)

File C:\Dev_Tools\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\solveset.py:1110, in _solveset(f, symbol, domain, _check)
   1106     result += _solve_radical(equation, u,
   1107                              symbol,
   1108                              solver)
   1109 elif equation.has(Abs):
-> 1110     result += _solve_abs(f, symbol, domain)
   1111 else:
   1112     result_rational = _solve_as_rational(equation, symbol, domain)

File C:\Dev_Tools\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\solveset.py:918, in _solve_abs(f, symbol, domain)
    916 """ Helper function to solve equation involving absolute value function """
    917 if not domain.is_subset(S.Reals):
--> 918     raise ValueError(filldedent('''
    919         Absolute values cannot be inverted in the
    920         complex domain.'''))
    921 p, q, r = Wild('p'), Wild('q'), Wild('r')
    922 pattern_match = f.match(p*Abs(q) + r) or {}

ValueError: 
Absolute values cannot be inverted in the complex domain.


How do I properly integrate this using Sympy?

I'm just getting Integral(sqrt(cos(2*x) + 1), (x, 0, pi)). Sympy 1.13.3.

I'm wondering if the problem doesn't lie just as much with the sqrt function as the cos. Sticking a re() around the expression gives a bizarrely over-complicated integrand that is only sorted out by using simplify().

Adding a simplification in there will produce the correct result, but I'm not sure why it is having an issue in the first place.
integrate(sqrt(1+cos(2*x)).simplify(), (x, 0, pi))  # 2*sqrt(2)


Well, works and thanks very much! But this is a good question either on why this works. I could think of by adding a "simplify" function, the sqrt(1+cos(2*x)) could be simplified to abs(cos(x)) and then solved the problem?

Yeah. If you just run the simplify portion and print out that result you'll see it does the same simplification you did in your handwritten code and simplifies the integrand to sqrt(2)*abs(cos(x)).

I would assume that it has something to do with how sympy handles trigonometric functions integrals.
The integrate() function doesn’t properly integrate cos(x), you have to use the trigintegrate() function to get the right result.
I do not know the reason for this however, and would appreciate any insight another might have onto this topic.

Well, this gives me errors as "TypeError: Can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'Wild'". But thanks for your suggestion still.
